# Exporting partial image using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, sentinel-2

When exporting an image to an asset in Google Earth Engine, the task seemingly runs fine but outputs only a tiny corner of my image. It is a filtered, cloud-masked Sentinel-2 scene with 16 bands (13+ image corrections). It does not display any error messages so I assume that GEE thinks it is executing the task I have asked for. One thought I had was that I have used up too much space in my GEE assets folder but this is not the case. I have also tried a drive export and the outcome is the same. The pictures show a) what I was expecting the output to be and b) what it actually was.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

[image: This is what I am expecting to get:][image: This is the actual output to my GEE assets]

```
var geometry: polygon, 5 vertices
var collection: ImageCollection "Sentinel-2 MSI: MultiSpectral Instrument, Level-1C"


 //define the cloud mask layer
function maskS2clouds(collection) {
  var qa = collection.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 <<10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 <<11;
  
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
    
  return collection.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

//image collection is filtered
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2015-08-26', '2015-08-28')
  .map(maskS2clouds);
  
//image with mask applied
var image = dataset.map(function(image) { return image.clip(geometry); });
Map.addLayer(image, RGB);

//exported to asset
Export.image.toAsset({
    image:dataset.first(), 
    description: '2015_CLOUDFREE',
    region: geometry,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var image = dataset.map(function(image) { return image.clip(geometry); });
Map.addLayer(image, RGB);
```

In this code you are displaying the entire image collection (despite its name, `image` is an `ImageCollection`) which is implicitly *mosaiced* by `Map.addLayer` (all images are combined, taking the most recent available pixel).

```
//exported to asset
Export.image.toAsset({
    image:dataset.first(), 
    ...
```

In this code you are taking only the first image of the collection. To get the same result as `addLayer`, use `image: dataset.mosaic(),` instead.